# How can I make ArcGIS 10.2 overwrite folders instead of pasting a new/copy folder (with a (1) suffix?)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

Just upgraded to 10.2 from 10.0 and I have always edited data on the C: drive then pasted this updated folder onto the "work" server.  In 10.0 the folder is overwritten. In 10.2 the folder is copied and given the (1) suffix giving me two folders.  How can I fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a little more information on how you are copying and pasting please. Are you copying using a geoprocessing tool, copy & paste in ArcCatalog or other method?

Comment: Could be copy/paste in Catalog window of ArcMap too.  I suspect that this is by design rather than a bug, and that an ArcCatalog tag on this may help to get it clarified even if it is the Catalog window being used, so am going to add that.